# Свободное место для данных приложения

Tags: android

Можно ли узнать, сколько места дается для хранения данных в приложении (`Internal Storage`)? Если же оно ограничивается только размерами SD карты или внутренней памятью телефона, то как можно узнать, в какой памяти находятся эти данные?

Comment: место ограничено только наличием свободной памяти на телефоне/sd карте.
Про место установки приложения не могу ничего сказать

Comment: по моим ощущениям нельзя узнать, где установлено приложение. Если вас волнует наличие свободной памяти, то проще просто проверить.  
Но можно принудительно заставить приложение устанавливаться только на sd-карту(если имеется) либо только в память телефона :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сначала определитесь, что вы понимаете под местом для хранения данных? Их несколько:
`Context.getFilesDir()`, `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`, `Context.getCacheDir()` и т.д. смотрите документацию по `Context`

Если известен путь то получить количество свободного места относительно просто:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
```

**Update**

> Цитата моим ощущениям нельзя узнать,
> где установлено приложение.

[[@Andreich](/users/5345/andreich)](/users/5345/andreich) стыдно должно быть. Программирование точная наука - здесь не место ощущениям Место установки пакета указывается в `PackageInfo`:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir; //путь к месту установки
```

Comment: sourceDir вернет путь что-то вроде /data/app/com.twitter.android-2.apk
и в нем не будет информации где приложение установлено: в памяти телефона или на cd карте